# How to populate UITextField with UIPickerView that have 3 components?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uipickerview

I did a date customized `UIPickerView` in my `ViewController` that have 3 components.

This picker work as an input to a `UITextField`. See some parts of my code to check how it was implemented.

```
var dataDia1: NSMutableArray!
var dataMes1: NSMutableArray!
var dataAno1: NSMutableArray!

@IBOutlet weak var pickerTextFieldInicio: UITextField!

let pickerViewInicio = UIPickerView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Declaração dos Picker

    pickerViewInicio.delegate = self
    pickerViewInicio.dataSource = self
    pickerViewInicio.showsSelectionIndicator = true
    pickerViewInicio.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 193/255, blue: 193/255, alpha: 1)

    self.dataDia1 = NSMutableArray()

    for dia in 1...31
    {
        dataDia1.addObject("\(dia)")
    }

    self.dataMes1 = NSMutableArray()

    for mes in 1...12
    {
        dataMes1.addObject("\(mes)")
    }

    self.dataAno1 = NSMutableArray()

    for ano in 1970...2016
    {
        dataAno1.addObject("\(ano)")
    }

    pickerTextFieldInicio.inputView = pickerViewInicio
```

My question is, how can I populate `pickerTextFieldInicio` with something like 31/10/2015?

I checked some posts realeted to Objective C, but I could not solve my problem as I'm using Swift.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `UIDatePicker` to the `MainStoryBoard`and then create an `@IBOutlet` for the `UIDatePicker` in the `ViewController.swift` name it whatever you want for instance we will use `diaPicked`

Next create an `@IBOutlet` for an `UILabel` and name it. 
Create a `@IBAction` for the DatePicker and name it. For intance let's say that we called it `pickerAction` Inside of the pickerAction add

```
@IBAction func PickerAction(sender: AnyObject) {

    var diaFormato = NSDateFormatter()
    diaFormato.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"
    var strDate = diaFormato.stringFromDate(diaPicked.date)
    self.selectedDate.text = strDate

}
```

I see that your variables are in spanish so I'll translate it for you since I speak spanish,

Agrega un `UIDatePicker` al `MainStoryBoard` y crea un `@IBOutlet` para el UIDatePicker en el ViewController.swift y lo puedes llamar lo que quieras pero por este ejemplo vamos a user `Dias`. y despues crea otro `IBOutlet` y le llamas `diaSelecionado`

Después crea un @IBAction para `Dias` y le llamas diasSelecionadoAcion que salga del UIDatePicker llamado `Dias`

```
   @IBAction func Dias (sender: AnyObject) {
    var diaFormato = NSDateFormatter()
    diaFormato.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"
    var strDate = diaFormato.stringFromDate(diaPicked.date)
    self.diaSelecionado.text = strDate
    }
```

Comment: Sounds Good, I will just need to make it programmatically, because The `UIDatePicker` will appear after click on `UITextField`.